# How to resolve ssl certificate errors for test automation in robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, robotframework

I'm getting ssl certificate error for our web application while running automation tests via robot framework. I tried below code with different chrome options but none of them worked that too with & without boolean value.

```
${list} =  Create List      --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=True
${args} =  Create Dictionary     args=${list}
${desired caps} =     Create Dictionary     chromeOptions=${args}
open browser  about:blank          ${BROWSER}  desired_capabilities=${desired_caps}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 11):

Both Firefox and Chrome (possibly others, did not test) support --ignore-certificate-errors option and Open Browser keyword has support for passing options to browsers, see https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
Foo
    Open Browser    https://expired.badssl.com/    firefox    options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    Capture Page Screenshot
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
```

Comment: @Harri, the above options arg works in SeleniumLibrary but what about Selenium2Library? https://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser the options keyword is no more supported there. What to do in this case?

Comment: In short, you need to use Create Webdriver keyword instead of Open Browser. Something like this (not tested at all):

`*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    Collections


*** Test Cases ***
Foobar
    ${list}    Create List    --ignore-certificate-errors
    ${args}    Create Dictionary    args=${list}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    ${args}
    Go To    https://expired.badssl.com/
    [Teardown]    Close all Browsers`

EDIT: The formatting got messed up, but you get the idea :)

Comment: this solution is effective and elegant, thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 3):

Firstly if you are on linux run the command

`pip list | grep robotframework`

if you are on windows open cmd and list all packages installed with  `pip list`  check if `robotframework  4.1` .If robot framework's version is less than 4.1 you have to upgrade package to any 4.1 or later version.
using

`sudo pip3 install robotframework --upgrade`

Now your script should work with

`options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below statements to avoid certificate issue in chrome browser(There are some issues in formatting so i am labelling statements as per sequence):

```
${chrome_options}=    Evaluate sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys
Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --ignore-certificate-errors
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
```